# Lambda expression for filtering 5 nested classes

Tags: c#, lambda, nested-loops

I have a nested object and I must filter it based on the deeper level.

These are my classes:

```
class Library    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public Library (string name, IList<Section> sections = null)  {
        Name = name;
        Sections = sections ?? new List<Section>();
    }
}

class Section    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Book> Books { get; set; }       
    public Section(string name, IList<Book> books = null) {
        Name = name;
        Books = books ?? new List<Book>();
    }
}

class Book {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Word> Words { get; set; }
    public Book(string name, IList<Word> words = null) {
        Name = name;
        Words = words ?? new List<Word>();
    }
}

class Word {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Character> Characters { get; set; }
    public Word(string name, IList<Character> characters = null) {
        Name = name;
        Characters = characters ?? new List<Character>();
    }
}

class Character {
    public char chrctr { get; set; }

    public Character(char character){
        chrctr = character;
    }
}
```

this is my object:

```
var char1 = new Character('a');
var char2 = new Character('b');
var char3 = new Character('c');
var char4 = new Character('d');
var char5 = new Character('e');

var word1 = new Word("word1", new Character[] { char1 });
var word2 = new Word("word2", new Character[] { char1, char2 });
var word3 = new Word("word3", new Character[] { char1, char2, char3 });
var word4 = new Word("word4", new Character[] { char1, char2, char3, char4 });
var word5 = new Word("word5", new Character[] { char1, char2, char3, char4, char5 });

var book1 = new Book("book1", new Word[] { word1 });
var book2 = new Book("book2", new Word[] { word1, word2 });
var book3 = new Book("book3", new Word[] { word1, word2, word3 });

var section1 = new Section("section1", new Book[] { book1, book2 });
var section2 = new Section("section2", new Book[] { book1, book2, book3 });

var library = new Library("library1", new Section[] { section1, section2 });
```

I want to replace my nested foreach with lambda expression for getting the filtered object, without using "add" and "get" functions for creating a new object:

```
var filteredLibrary = new Library("filteredLibrary");
foreach (var section in library.Sections)
{
    foreach (var book in section.Books)
    {
        foreach (var word in book.Words)
        {
            var chars = word.Characters.Where(c => c.chrctr == 'd').ToList();
            if (chars.Count > 0)
            {
                filteredLibrary.Sections.Add(section);  //if it doesn't exist
                filteredLibrary.GetSection(section.Name).Books.Add(book);  //if it doesn't exist
                filteredLibrary.GetSection(section.Name).GetBook(book.Name).Words.Add(chars);  //if it doesn't exist
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you post me an example,please?

Comment: Is your nested `foreach` working? It seems to me that you are adding an existing, unfiltered section (which still has all of its books) to your "filtered library," and then re-adding the required books to it. The intent is clear (I think), but a direct conversion of that code to Linq wouldn't give you the result you need.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the last line end `.Words.Add(word)`, and then also add the characters to the word?

Comment: this code is an example, it doesn't work. My idea is to use lambda expression for getting the filtered object, without using "add" and "get" functions for creating a new object

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you should go this route as the whole thing, generally, looks a bit too complex. I'd try to simplify logic first.

Otherwise, here is what ReSharper suggests (using [query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx))

```
var filteredLibrary = new Library("filteredLibrary");
foreach (var section in 
        from section in library.Sections 
        from book in section.Books 
        from word in book.Words 
        let chars = word.Characters
                        .Where(c => c.chrctr == 'd')
                        .ToList() 
        where chars.Count > 0
        select section)
{
    //if it doesn't exist
    filteredLibrary.Sections.Add(section);  
    filteredLibrary.GetSection(section.Name).Books.Add(book);
    filteredLibrary.GetSection(section.Name).GetBook(book.Name).Words.Add(chars);
}
```